# how to install onvif library in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, import, onvif

I am just on ONVIF use. I have downloaded "onvifdm-onvif.tar.gz" from http://synesis.ru/en/surveillance/downloads, in which there are four files (onvif.discovery.dll, onvif.services.dll, onvif.session.dll, and onvif.utils.dll). I also got a demo code from this forum, in which there are line like this "import org.onvif.ver10.schema.SystemDateTime;"

Apparentlly, the demo code couldn't find the onvif library since the error message said "The import org.onvif cannot be resolved".

Could anyone let me know how to find the proper onvif library, how to import it correctly into my eclipse? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best think to do is to start from the wsdl files and generate your classes. Visual studio supports it, or you could use gsoap.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try to generate my classes.

Answer (score 2):

Or Netbeans -> new project -> java project -> finish.
right cick on project -> new -> jaxb bindings and import onvif.xsd -> finish
it generates a lot files etc.

eclipse -> your_project -> src -> right click -> import -> general -> folder -> and search your netbeans folder/build/generated-sources/jaxb.

import the whole jaxb folder and than it works!